# Django filter query with date and integer

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I try to write query which must show planes, which working life is over.
Models.py

```
class Aircraft(models.Model):
    registration_num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    airplane_age = models.IntegerField()
    commision_day = models.DateField()
```

Views.py

```
def query1(request):
    air_list = Aircraft.objects.filter(commision_day__year__lte=(datetime.date.today().year - 10))
    #air_list = Aircraft.objects.extra(where=['commision_day + airplane_age < CURDATE()'])
    #air_list = Aircraft.objects.extra(where=["commision_day+airplane_age<datetime.date.today()"]) F('airplane_age') year=10, month=1, day=1
```

Data example

```
commision_day = 1995.10.05
airplane_age = 15
```

I try many methods to do, but no one works((((
So i need to show plnes which commision day + airplane_age < today day
Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If so, what are they?

Comment: @itsjeyd I tried many variations with different errors)) So, in situation above:  `Join on field 'commision_day' not permitted. Did you misspell 'year' for the lookup type?` - because using __year and __lte together is mistaken. =)

Comment: OK, I think you can try comparing the value of `commision_day` against another `datetime.date` with appropriate values directly. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20597416/1199226) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting up a `datetime.date` object to use as a threshold, and then filter `Aircraft` objects against that by their date directly:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
threshold = datetime.date(today.year-10, today.month, today.day)
Aircraft.objects.filter(commision_day__lte=threshold)
```

Comment: This method does not work with "airplane_age" field. But you give me a good idea! I wrote this and it's work: `today = datetime.date.today() air_list = Aircraft.objects.all() for air in air_list: threshold = datetime.date(today.year - air.airplane_age, today.month, today.day) if air.commision_day <= threshold: air_list = air_list.filter(registration_num__gt=air.registration_num)` With formatting: http://pastie.org/8554147

Answer (score 0):

Try this queryset:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Aircraft.objects.filter(commision_day__lte=(datetime.now() - timedelta(years=10)))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I tried this before ask. `datetime.timedelta()` has not parameter `years`. [Timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).=(

Comment: You're right, sorry.. maybe you could use [relativedelta](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) instead `timedelta`..

Answer (score 0):

The goal here is to combine the values of two fields, and compare the result with a value calculated in the current process, essentially:

```
Aircraft.objects.extra(where=['somedate + years < today'])
```

The expression within `where=['...']` must be valid SQL and the right syntax will depend on your database backend. That is, you need to know the right way to add years to a date to form the `somedate + years` correctly, for example in SQLite it would be like this:

```
date(commision_day, '+' || airplane_age || ' year') < date('now')
```

This is more efficient than [your solution](http://pastie.org/8554147), but it is not portable, as it depends on the database backend due to non-standard syntax of date operations.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this method give error `Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

Comment: Fixed, see my updated answer (wrapping the year in `str(...)`)

Comment: `operator does not exist: date < integer` =(

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.db.models import F


Aircraft.objects.filter(commision_day__lte=datetime.now()-relativedelta(years=F('airplane_age')))
```

Comment: This will raise: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'F'`

Comment: @funnydman is right. `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'CombinedExpression'` error is raised